# Complex Summation

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it possible to use a complex number like this: (I don't know how to call this)

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{5i}{2 \over 5}n^3$

Also, how would the answer be? Do we still use the formula

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{x}{n^3}=[{n(n+1)\over 2}]^2$, making the answer $5+i$ ?

Comment: If you start at $1$, at which step will you reach $5i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a sum from $n=0$ to $5i$ makes no sense.  What is true is that the function $f(x)$ defined for positive integers $x$ by  $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x n^3$$
has an analytic continuation to the complex plane given by the formula $$ F(z) = \left(\frac{z(z+1)}{2}\right)^2 $$
However, this analytic continuation is not unique, e.g. you could add any multiple of $\sin(\pi z)$ to the function and it would have the same value at the positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just as easily ask the question what does it mean to take

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\pi} \frac{2}{5}n^3. $$

In general, we use the summation sign to denote a sum of discrete elements parametrized by a natural number. In moving to real number parametrisations, we introduce integrals instead, something like

$$ \int_1^\pi \frac{2}{5}x^3~dx,$$

and while this doesn't generally equal the sum when the terminals of the integral are natural numbers, one can choose the function more carefully to be a step function to obtain the original values.

Similarly, we can take integrals in the complex plane, along curves which might start at $1$ and end at $5i$.